# What is the point of in-place server configuration in PhpStorm when server files are both local and remote at the same time?

Tags: phpstorm

What is the point of in-place server configuration in PhpStorm, when as defined in the docs in in-place server configuration:

> The web server is running on your computer, your project is under its document root (for example, in the /htdocs folder), and you do your development directly on the server.

So, what is the point of making a server connection when I'm directly editing/using the files from my server, and they are both local and remote at the same time?

Also, I've set up everything according to the docs for in-place server, and I can't find any server when I open remote hosts window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this server connection setup, you can tell the IDE to preview your files on your in-place web server instead of the IDE built-in webserver (`http://localhost:63342`) when you click the browser icon on the browsers bar